# How to deal with circular json structure in Vue2 PHP application

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, json-api

In my frontend I was dealing circular structure and the response was returning an infinite loop.
I am a frontend developer but to fix this issue I converted the backend from this point:

```
if ($repositoryModel->parentElementId === null) {
            $childElementResource->parent = $context->resource('parent')
                ->newModel($context)
                ->setId($repositoryModel->parentElId);
        } else {
            $childElementResource->parent = $context->resource('child')
                ->newModel($context)
                ->setId($repositoryModel->parentElementId);
        }
```

to that:

```
if ($repositoryModel->parentElementId === null) {
            $childElementResource->parentId = $repositoryModel->parentElId;
        } else {
            $childElementResource->parentId = $repositoryModel->parentElementId;
        }
```

so circular structure is fixed but now in response, I get the parent null. So the parent looks like this:

```
"parent": {
                "data": null
            },
```

instead of this:

```
"parent": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "child",
                    "id": "418"
                }
            },
```

so my question is how should I try to fix this issue. Is this an issue for frontend or backend? is there any recommendation for fixin in backend.

Thanks.

Comment: A JSON response is just text: it cannot be used to encode a circular structure. If your data can reference itself like this you need to restructure your response and how you handle it.

Comment: Should I do it in backend or frontend? Because in frontend, it is really hard since I get the response in a loop

Comment: Where do you create the JSON response?

Comment: In backend. When the backend was like this:
if ($repositoryModel->parentElementId === null) {
            $childElementResource->parent = $context->resource('parent')
                ->newModel($context)
                ->setId($repositoryModel->parentElId);
        } else {
            $childElementResource->parent = $context->resource('child')
                ->newModel($context)
                ->setId($repositoryModel->parentElementId);
        }

I was getting the response correct in postman but in frontend in was in indefinite loop

Comment: @SimonBrahan A JSON may be just text. But the JSON:API specification describes how records and relationships between them could be serialized as JSON. This allows circular relationships.

Comment: If you're seeing a sensible response in postman, the backend is already doing what you need. You question is then "what should my frontend do with this?". If you're still struggling, try another question containing your JSON response and the front end code that's getting stuck.